# braintreepayments duplicate class issue

Tags: java, android, kotlin, braintree

[image]

These two libraries used to duplicate issues occurred, please help me!

```
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.18.0'
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:6.4.0'
```

kindly provide to solutions

Comment: try delete the folder c/users/youruer/.gradle in your pc

Comment: You can not read the full error message in the screenshot, you should post it as text.

If you are using gradle for dependecies you can use something like this to exclude specific ones: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps

Comment: Take a look at the exact API docs package lists and i think you will find that one of the two api jar's is not required because the other jar contains all its' classes too. You are probably calling more than one copy of the class, of there is no mechanism to handle that , so an error occurs.